# JSON QuickChart.io Change the Chart Size

Tags: json, chart.js, powerapps, quickchart

I am creating a QuickChart.io using Chart.JS within a PowerApps canvas and am having some issues with formatting. Everything works on the visualization (filtering, rendering, etc.) but I am trying to remove the gridlines and resize the display area but the formatting options are not showing up. Any idea what's causing this?

```
"https://quickchart.io/chart?c="&EncodeUrl("{
   'type': 'bar',
   'data': {
     'labels': ["&Concat(Filter(Table2,Scenario=_code),"'"&'X-Axis'&"',")&"],
     'datasets': [
       {
         'label': 'Dataset 2',
         'backgroundColor': 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)',
         'borderColor': 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
         'borderWidth': 1,
         'data': ["&Concat(Filter(Table2,Scenario=_code),"'"&DataSet1&"',")&"]
       }
     ]
   },
   'options': 
   {
     'elements': {
       'rectangle': {
         'borderWidth': 2
       }
     },
     'responsive': true,
     'maintainAspectRatio': false,
     'legend': {
       'display': false
     },
     'grid': {
       display: false
     },
     'title': {
       'display': true,
       'text': 'Revenue'
     }
   }
 }")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your config is invalid, there is no grid option in the root of the options.

Depending on if quick chart is using chartjs V2 or v3 you need to configure it in the scales section

V2: `options.scales.xAxes[0].gridLines.display`

V3: `options.scales.x.grid.display`

And then you replace x by y to remove the y grid

Comment: Thank you! Any idea why the 'responsive': true, and 'maintainAspectRatio': false are not working here when I adjust the sizing?